# Worklight: error Push Notification on Android

Tags: push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

Please help me! I've tried for a week to fix my push notification demo but it still doesn't work! Device could not recieve messages after I quit my application.

This is the android element from application-descriptor.xml file (with Browser Key):

```
 <android version="1.0" securityTest="mobile-securityTest">
        <worklightSettings include="false"/>
        <pushSender key="AIzaSyBmDTJw8IQAA1MmTF9MkSQUQXYxoFBKKtk" senderId="430560385547"/>
        <security>
            <encryptWebResources enabled="false"/>
            <testWebResourcesChecksum enabled="false" ignoreFileExtensions="png, jpg, jpeg, gif, mp4, mp3"/>
            <publicSigningKey>PushNotificationMyAppAndroid</publicSigningKey>
            <packageName>com.MyApp</packageName>
        </security>
        <compressWebResources enabled="true"/>
    </android>
```

This is main.js file:

```
$('#isSupportbtn').bind("click", isSupport);
$('#isSubscibedbtn').bind("click",isSubscribed);
$('#subscribebtn').bind("click",doSubscribe);
$('#unSubscribebtn').bind("click",doUnSubscribe);

function isSupport(){
    var isSupport = false;
    if(WL.Client.Push){
        isSupport = WL.Client.Push.isPushSupported();
    }
    alert(isSupport);
}
function isSubscribed(){
    var isSubscribed = false;
    if(WL.Client.Push){
        isSubscribed = WL.Client.Push.isSubscribed('myPush');
    }
    alert(isSubscribed);
}

if(WL.Client.Push){
    WL.Client.Push.onReadyToSubscribe = function(){
        $('#subscribebtn').removeAttr('disabled');
        $('#unSubscribebtn').removeAttr('disabled');
        WL.Client.Push.registerEventSourceCallback(
            "myPush",
            "AdapterAuth",
            "pushEventSource",
            pushNotificationReceived
        );
    };
}
function doSubscribe(){
    WL.Client.Push.subscribe("myPush",{
        onSuccess:function(){
            alert("Success");
        },
        onFailure:function(){
            alert("Fail");
        }
    });
}
function doUnSubscribe(){
    WL.Client.Push.unsubscribe("myPush",{
        onSuccess:function(){
            alert("Success");
        },
        onFailure:function(){
            alert("Fail");
        }
    });
}
function pushNotificationReceived(props, payloads){
    alert("pushNotificationReceived invoked");
    alert("props :: " + JSON.stringify(props));
    alert("payload :: " + JSON.stringify(payload));
}
```

This is AdapterAuth-impl.js file:

```
function getUser() {
    return {Data:[{username:'hcv',password:"123456",bagde:'3',message:'hi, Jane'},{username:'vi',password:'123',bagde:'3',message:'hi, Luffy'}]};
}
function onAuthRequired(headers,errorMessage){
    errorMessage = errorMessage ? errorMessage:null;
    return{
        authRequired:true,
        errorMessage:errorMessage
    };
}
function submitAuth(username,password) {
    var response = {Data:[{username:'hcv',password:"123456",bagde:'3',message:'hi, Jane'},{username:'vi',password:'123',bagde:'3',message:'hi, Luffy'}]};
    for (var i=0;i<response.Data.length;i++){
        if(username === response.Data[i].username && password === response.Data[i].password){
            var Identity={
                userId: username,
                displayName: username,
                attributes:{foo:"bar"}
            };
            WL.Server.setActiveUser("AuthLoginRealm", Identity);
            return{
                authRequired: false
            };
        }
    }
    return onAuthRequired(null,"Invalid login credentials");

}
function onLogout(){
    WL.Server.setActiveUser("AuthLoginRealm", null);
    WL.Logger.debug("Logged out");
}
WL.Server.createEventSource({
    name:"pushEventSource",
    poll:{
        interval:60,
        onPoll:"submitNotifications"
    },
    securityTest:"mobile-securityTest",

});
function submitNotifications() {
    var response = {Data:[{username:'hcv',password:"123456",bagde:"3",message:"hi,Jane"},{username:"vi",password:"123",bagde:"1",message:"hi, Luffy"}]};
    var messages = response.Data;
    for(var i=0; i < messages.length;i++){
        var userId = WL.Server.getActiveUser("AuthLoginRealm");
        if(messages[i].username === userId){
        var userSubscription = WL.Server.getUserNotificationSubscription("AdapterAuth.pushEventSource", messages[i].username);

        if(userSubscription === null){
            return {result:"no user was found:"+messages[i].username};
        }
        var notification = WL.Server.createDefaultNotification(messages[i].message, messages[i].bagde,{foo:'bar'});
        WL.Logger.debug("submitNotification >> userId :: " + messages[i].username + ", text :: " + messages[i].message);
        WL.Server.notifyAllDevices(userSubscription, notification);
        WL.Logger.error("UserId"+messages[i].username+"not found");
        }
    }
}
```

This is error:

```
06-24 09:27:11.927: E/ActivityThread(3096): Activity com.MyApp.MyApp has leaked IntentReceiver com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver@41c85190 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
06-24 09:27:11.927: E/ActivityThread(3096): android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Activity com.MyApp.MyApp has leaked IntentReceiver com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver@41c85190 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
06-24 09:27:11.927: E/ActivityThread(3096):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:763)
06-24 09:27:11.927: E/ActivityThread(3096):     at android.app.LoadedApk.getReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:567)
06-24 09:27:11.927: E/ActivityThread(3096):     at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:1055)
06-24 09:27:11.927: E/ActivityThread(3096):     at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1042)
06-24 09:27:11.927: E/ActivityThread(3096):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:348)
06-24 09:27:11.927: E/ActivityThread(3096):     at com.google.android.gcm.GCMRegistrar.setRetryBroadcastReceiver(GCMRegistrar.java:293)
06-24 09:27:11.927: E/ActivityThread(3096):     at com.google.android.gcm.GCMRegistrar.register(GCMRegistrar.java:215)
06-24 09:27:11.927: E/ActivityThread(3096):     at com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.Push.subscribe(Push.java:331)
06-24 09:27:11.927: E/ActivityThread(3096):     at com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.Push.access$400(Push.java:45)
06-24 09:27:11.927: E/ActivityThread(3096):     at com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.Push$2.run(Push.java:233)
06-24 09:27:11.927: E/ActivityThread(3096):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
06-24 09:27:11.927: E/ActivityThread(3096):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
06-24 09:27:11.927: E/ActivityThread(3096):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: Did you try the sample push notifications project?

Comment: yes, I did...It's ok.

Comment: I just added my error, it occurs after I quit my application...

Comment: that error also happens in the sample (which works and receives a notifications even when the app is closed). that's not the real issue.

Comment: So, what is my issue?

Comment: I don't know yet. Can you export and upload the project to Dropbox so it could be debugged?

Comment: Here is it: https://www.dropbox.com/s/mb6yyxzpd2qwlu9/PushNotificationV3.zip

Comment: Oh, what did I do wrong, @IdanAdar? I'd like to get the message from my data and send it to server then it will appears as the worklight push notification sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested your application. I managed to receive the push notification in all 3 scenarios: when the app is in the foreground, when the app is in the background and when the app is close.

I have 2 comments:

1. `var response = {Data:[{username:'hcv',password:"123456",bagde:"3",message:"hi,Jane"},{username:"vi",password:"123",bagde:"1",message:"hi,Julian"}]};`

   Here, the badge should not be in double-quotes. Remove the quotes.
2. The `submitNotifications` function... I see that you are building everything inside of it - the notification text and the user to be sent to, but this is not how it is supposed to be(!).

   This function is supposed to *receive* these: `submitNotifications(userId, 
   notifivcationText)`

   So I don't know how you are sending the push notifications, it looks wrong to me.
   Anyway, to get it to work I had to change

   `if( messages[i].username === userId){ ...`

   To:

   `if( true || messages[i].username === userId){ ...`

I strongly suggest to re-read the Push Notifications training module.